# What are the authentication aspects of Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm thinking of using GCP's Cloud Functions for a project, but there are several things I don't understand.

1. Can anyone send an HTTP request to my function? If so, can they run up the bill?
2. Can I authenticate myself in a cloud function? E.g. Send credentials to it and then have the function retrieve some data if the credentials are valid? Is this secure over HTTP?

Thank you for the info.

Comment: Question about your first sentence: If I understand you mean that you need to configure your future request with the paiement functions? if it's true, The billing is related to the user (you can add custome user with billing account)

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/) about this.

Anyone can access your function [without authentication](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation) if you give "allUsers" access.  This is not the default situation for gcloud deployments, but it is the default when you're deploying the function with the Firebase CLI.

Otherwise, you will need to [provide a service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#controlling_access_on_a_function) that has been given access to invoke the function.  The linked documentation should cover everything you need to know.

Comment: Thank you, I'll aim to follow that.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your Cloud Function to require authentication and authorization of the caller ... see [Managing Access via IAM](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access).

In addition, when you make further GCP API calls from within the context of your Cloud Function, your cloud function has a default identity that those requests will be made as.  You can change this identity and give that identity suitable permissions to be able to access the services request. See [Function Identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity).